# Compiling Errors with Arrays and 'struct'?

Tags: c++, arrays, compilation

I'm just about at the end of my first programming class, (first programming class) and I require assistance with my code, seeing as how I am getting unclear compiling errors.

First of all, there is the fact that the array I am attempting to load is giving me problems.

```
string stu[15];
stu[0]= Billy;
stu[1]= Bobby;
stu[2]= Bailee;
stu[3]= Barney;
stu[4]= Bambi;
stu[5]= Barbie;
stu[6]= Barrie;
stu[7]= Barry;
stu[8]= Benny;
stu[9]= Barkley;
stu[10]= Bennie;
stu[11]= Bonnie;
stu[12]= Bernie;
stu[13]= Bertie;
stu[14]= George;
```

Apparently it says every one of those are undeclared. But I thought that was almost the point of arrays? To not spend all your time declaring variables?

My other problem is with this code...

```
int name_count = 0;

while (name_count < 15) 
{ 
    inputFile >> (stu[0]); 
    if (!inputFile.good()) break; 
    ++name_count; 
}
```

I'm trying to load in data from a `.txt` file into an array, and I'm confused on how to do this.

All code together:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string inputFile;
    string stu[15];
    stu[0] = Billy;
    stu[1] = Bobby;
    stu[2] = Bailee;
    stu[3] = Barney;
    stu[4] = Bambi;
    stu[5] = Barbie;
    stu[6] = Barrie;
    stu[7] = Barry;
    stu[8] = Benny;
    stu[9] = Barkley;
    stu[10] = Bennie;
    stu[11] = Bonnie;
    stu[12] = Bernie;
    stu[13] = Bertie;
    stu[14] = George;

    ofstream(studentFile)("Students.txt");
    studentFile.open("Students.txt");

    studentFile << " STUDENT INFO HERE ";
    studentFile.close();

    int name_count = 0;

    while (name_count < 15) {
        inputFile >> (stu[0]);
        if (!inputFile.good())
            break;
        ++name_count;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I keep getting the compiling errors:

> no match for 'operator>>' in 'inputFile >> stu[0]'

and

> 'struct std::string' has no member named 'good'

Pretty sure I'm missing something here...any help woudld be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: don't bring us programming class homework.

Answer (score 1):

> no match for 'operator>>' in 'inputFile >> stu[0]'

You can't use << or >> with strings.

`inputFile` is of std::string type and does **not** have any member function *good()*. You probably meant to use an input file stream (*ifstream*).

Also, avoid the use of `system()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to wrap your strings with a `""`

```
"Bernie"
```

C++ currently things you are trying to assign your struct to objects `Billy`, `Bobby`, etc.., etc...

this is because C++ requires explicit type declaration, the compiler doesn't implicity know `Billy` should be a string and not an object. You need to use `"Billy` to denote a string type.